# C++ Segmentation Fault -- something different here

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am java programmer but still finding this c++ code not working. When I run this project (Codeblock), I get the segmentation fault. I searched internet but couldn't find exactly what causing this error.

1) main.cpp

```
#include "performancetest.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    performancetest *Obj = new performancetest;
    Obj->test1();
    Obj->test2();
    Obj->~performancetest();
    return 0;
}
```

2) performancetest.cpp

```
#include "performancetest.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
performancetest::performancetest()
{
}

performancetest::~performancetest()
{
}

void performancetest::test1()
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    const int g_n = 500;
    float TestData[g_n][g_n][g_n];
    t1 = clock();
    for (int k=0; k<g_n; k++) // K
    {
        for (int j=0; j<g_n; j++) // J
        {
            for (int i=0; i<g_n; i++) // I
            {
                TestData[i][j][k] = 0.0f;
            }
        }
    }
    //start time t2
    t2 = clock();
    double val = this->diffclock(t1, t2);
    cout << "Time: " << val << endl;
}

void performancetest::test2()
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    const int g_n = 500;
    float TestData[g_n][g_n][g_n];
    //start time t1
    t1 = clock();
    for (int k=0; k<g_n; k++) // K
    {
        for (int j=0; j<g_n; j++) // J
        {
            for (int i=0; i<g_n; i++) // I
            {
                TestData[i][j][k] = 0.0f;
            }
        }
    }
    //start time t2
    t2 = clock();
    double val = this->diffclock(t1, t2);
    cout << "Time: " << val << endl;
}

double performancetest::diffclock(clock_t clock1,clock_t clock2)
{
    double diffticks=clock1-clock2;
    double diffms=(diffticks)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    return diffms;
}
```

3)performancetest.h

```
#ifndef PERFORMANCETEST_H
#define PERFORMANCETEST_H
#include <time.h>
class performancetest
{
public:
    performancetest();
    void test1();
    double diffclock(clock_t, clock_t);
    void test2();
    virtual ~performancetest();
protected:
private:
};
#endif // PERFORMANCETEST_H
```

And, here comes, segmentation fault as shown in below picture
[image]

Comment: 1. `using std` is bad - google it. 2. Indent the code to make it readable. 3. Perhaps running it via a debugger would at least tell you the line wher e it occurs

Comment: `float TestData[g_n][g_n][g_n];` You are trying to put a 500MB data structure onto the stack. Typically, the stack is limited to 2MB or so. I suspect you are seeing a stack overflow. Make that variable `static`, or allocate it on the heap.

Comment: Don't call the destructor directly, call `delete` on pointers you allocate with`new`.

Comment: change g_n to something small, like 10 and see if it works.  Always compile with the debug flags until you get your code working, so you can run in the debugger.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, you're right. Thanks. Now, How can I change 2MB stack size?

Comment: Depends on the tools you use. There's usually a linker option for that. Though you would not normally want to increase stack size. You instead would want to avoid placing large data structures on the stack in the first place.

Comment: Ok. Thank you man. I will search that.

Comment: You must absolutely learn how to at least tell **which line** causes a crash. The ideal way to do so is with a debugger, of course, but even some `std::cout` lines to find out until when the program is still "alive" are better than *nothing*.

Comment: In addition to @latedeveloper: don't use new or delete.

Answer (score 1):

Your multidimensional arrays are too big for the stack, so a stack overflow exception is thrown. You must allocate TestData on the heap.

You can do it like this:

```
const int g_n = 500;
typedef float MultiDimArray[g_n][g_n];
MultiDimArray* TestData = new MultiDimArray[g_n];
//...
delete[] TestData; //deallocate
```

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeT